# cannot compile tornadofx app into standalone jar

Tags: java, kotlin

I am pretyy new to Kotlin and to JVM overall, I  would to compile my helloworld kotlin app into a standalone jar which would be executable on a client machine (which has a JRE)

I am sure that I am using Java 1.8 with JavaFx included, I also have following dependencies in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>no.tornado</groupId>
        <artifactId>tornadofx</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.14</version>
    </dependency>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src</sourceDirectory>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>main.kt</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Running the following

`kotlinc /home/denis/prg/java/kot/src/main.kt -include-runtime -d main.jar -jvm-target 1.8`
gives

`src/main.kt:3:8: error: unresolved reference: tornadofx`

Also, running `maven clean package` produces a SNAPSHOT jar, but I cannot run it?.. Java gives `Could not find or load main class main.kt`

How can I make something usable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After sleeping and googling I found out!

Despite the fact that my main file is called `Main.kt`, in manifest note that the file must be called `MainKt`:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals> <goal>single</goal> </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>MainKt</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Also I was not sure why would I need to use `kotlinc` with a classpath pointing to `javaFx.jar`, and in fact, I don't, that why I have maven.
Also, use JDK 1.8.0_144 (`sdk use java 8u144-zulu`)